# Issues with Pushing to new Git repo

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, git-lfs

I've looked at countless other topics (granted they are all older than 3years) and I'm starting to get rather frustrated. I've resorted to creating new repos just to try and get this working. I've created repos from both GitHub desktop and GitHub.

I'm trying to setup version control for a Unity Project. I'm using LFS to handle the larger files/models/textures etc. (currently only 6 things need lfs)

I have used `git config --bool core.bare true` to try and make my repo bare.

I have tried to checkout of the master branch, into a temp one, and back into the master to push. I also tried to create a develop branch from the master branch, pushing to that did not work either.

All the fixes I see that work for other people are not working for me. I always get the `[remote rejected]` error when I `git push origin master`

Here is the error i get:
`! [remote rejected] master -> (per-receive hook declined)`

Is LFS causing this? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: the repo was created by you right? so it doesn't seems to be a permissions issue. right username/password and/or ssh key? have you tried both authentication methods? (username/pass and ssh) ?

Comment: yeah, created by me. and git hub uses an ssh key and bash uses user/pass so have tried both

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/40 ?

Open your project > Settings and go to "Protected branches", select: "Developers can push

Comment: There were no protected branches in the project. I also tried creating a temp branch to push to and merge into the master and that didn't work either. Couldn't push into temp branch.